# Interacting with firefox using an external program

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, chromium

I am looking for a way to interact with a web page and enter data to certain fields in it using an external program that interact with Firefox (or Chromium) web browser. The best I could find is the console commands for the browser, but they only let you go to a certain URL and not interact with the pages' content. I have also tried looking for some extension to do the job but I could not find any. Any suggestions?

Comment: In chrome/chromium you can use [Native Application Messages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create Chrome extension that communicates with your application via Chrome Native Messaging API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and the tools mentioned at [Selenium alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426190/selenium-alternatives).